# Discrepancy in BscScan Inward Transaction Listing - Need Insights

Tags: bscscan

Hello Ethereum community,

I'm facing an odd issue with BscScan, and while I understand it's primarily for Binance Smart Chain, I believe many of the principles carry over from Ethereum, and the knowledgeable folks here might have come across similar issues.

For address 0xeb24a756bdcc1059abcf408d5b916a0f8060477a, there's a confirmed inward transaction with the hash 0x1a6d37f9de48838a949be179fb8bddb223938e7bb2d7f395b1b3f359939ae017 ([Explorer page](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1a6d37f9de48838a949be179fb8bddb223938e7bb2d7f395b1b3f359939ae017)). However, when reviewing the inward transaction list at https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0xeb24a756bdcc1059abcf408d5b916a0f8060477a&f=3, the transaction is conspicuously missing.

I've double-checked the addresses and transaction hashes for accuracy. I've also attempted to contact BscScan directly but encountered CAPTCHA issues on their feedback form.

Has anyone here experienced a similar issue with BscScan or even Etherscan? Any insights or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a support question for a commercial third party product. People outside the internal product team cannot answer the question. This forum is not for complaining about poor product support and voluntary people should not spend their time to support any company for free.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa So, is this a bug?

Comment: @SmartManoj It doesn't show as a regular transaction, but it appears in the Token Transfers (BEP-20) tab.